# insert string into text [] column

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have the following issue.

1. I will receive input as a text from a webservice to insert into a certain psql table. assume

   create table test ( id serial, myvalues text[])

the recieved input will be:
   `insert into test(myvalues) values ('this,is,an,array');`

2. I want to create a trigger before insert that will be able to convert this string to a text [] and insert it

first Idea that came in my mind was to create a trigger before insert

```
create function test_convert() returns trigger as $BODY%
 BEGIN
   new.myvalues = string_to_array(new.myvalues,',')
   RETURNS NEW
 END; $BODY$ language plpgsql
```

but this did not work

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`string_to_array`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) function to convert your string into an string array within your insert query:

```
INSERT INTO test ( myvalues )
VALUES ( string_to_array( 'this,is,an,array', ',' ) );
```

Comment: The question was different I meant that the insert command I have from a webservice is an insert as string can I do it from a trigger side?

Comment: You can't change the type of a value inside an insert query via a before trigger or any other means. You have to change the initial insert query to pass through the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you receive text in the following format `this is an array` and you want to convert it to `this,is,an,array` then you can use `string_to_array('this is an array', ' ')` and it will be converted. However if you are receiving comma separated then you can just used it.

Comment: Try to insert it will throw an error because the insert is expecting an array

Answer (score 0):

Creating the Table Schema Like this,

```
CREATE TABLE expert (
    id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(36),
    twitter_id VARCHAR(40),
    coin_supported text[],
    start_date TIMESTAMP,
    followers BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

Inserting values like this will help you to insert array,

```
insert into expert(id, name, twitter_id, coin_supported, start_date, followers) values('9ed1cdf2-564c-423e-b8e2-137eg', 'dev1', 'dev1@twitter', '{"btc","eth"}', current_timestamp, 12);
```